# Class with same name in two assemblies (intentionally)

Tags: c#, namespaces, class

I'm in the process of migrating a library that is written in C++ and has a C# wrapper. The C# wrapper (`LibWrapper`) has a set of classes with namespaces, like:

```
namespace MyNamespace
   class MyClass
   class MyOtherClass
```

My new library, `LibraryCS` contains the same namespaces and class names as `LibWrapper` (per user requirement), so I also have:

```
namespace MyNamespace
   class MyClass
   class MyOtherClass
```

Now that the migration is done, I'm in the process of creating a test that compares the results of using both libraries, to validate the migration. However, when I try to reference `MyNamespace.MyClass` I get a compiler error (expectedly!) that says "MyNamespace.MyClass is defined in both LibWrapper and LibraryCS".

Is there any trick around this issue, that will allow me to use two classes with the exact same name but from different assemblies in the same client code?

Alternatively, is there any other way to test this?

Renaming the migrated namespace to something like `MyNamespace2` will of course work, but we were asked not to do it, in order to keep the client code easier to migrate.

Comment: Would it be okay to write a wrapper around one of the classes that exists in another namespace?

Comment: If I'm able to run both in the same test code, it may be acceptable. It will be a wrapper only used for test purposes.

Comment: "*in order to keep the client code easier to migrate*" I feel your pain of being "managed". (◔_◔) ;^D

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use an [extern alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias) to reference types with the same fully qualified name from different assemblies.  Select the reference to LibraryCS and update Aliases in the properties page from "global" to "LibraryCS", and add `extern alias LibraryCS;` to the top of your source file, and then you can use `LibraryCS::MyNamespace.MyClass` to refer to the class in LibraryCS.  You can use `MyNamespace.MyClass` or `global::MyNamespace.MyClass` to refer to the class in LibWrapper, or you can use an alias for that reference as well.

Comment: I agree with Quartermeister. See below for more reference:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/27/774692.aspx

Comment: @Kari your link is broken.

Answer (score 4):

In order to load both of these classes in the same executable, you could to load them in a separate Application Domain.  This would let you test the assembly, then fully unload it and load the second one and test it.

For details on how to do this, see [How to: Load Assemblies into an Application Domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25y1ya39.aspx) and [Unload an Application Domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5b8a8f9.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Saw this question and answer and it helped me. How ever for those who need a detailed explanation on the same, i found a [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2005/11/30/c-2-0-using-different-versions-of-the-same-dll-in-one-application/) which is really useful.

Extract from the link.

**Using different versions of the same dll in one application**

step 1:  using the **VS IDE**. Add the reference to both the dlls in your client application solution. Then in the Solution Explorer under the reference node select the first (old version) class library. In the property window change Aliases field from **global** to **oldVer**. lly, **newVer** for the N**ewer version**.

Step 2: use the below code as the first statements where you plan to reference it

```
extern alias oldVer;
extern alias newVer;
```

now to use,

```
Console.WriteLine(oldVer::MyLibrary.MyClass.method());
Console.WriteLine(newVer::MyLibrary.MyClass.method());
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You could load the first assembly at runtime then use reflection to instantiate it and execute it's method.  Then unload that assembly, load the second assembly and use reflection to create it and run its methods.</strike>

It'd probably be easier to use 2 separate processes then compare the resulting output...

Comment: You can't unload an assembly directly, only an AppDomain.  In order to do this, you need a separate appdomain with that assembly.

Comment: Good call, would have to take down the AppDomain to unload the assembly, I'll edit the response.