# Specify which assembly to use for a class with same name and namespace

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Class with same name in two assemblies (intentionally)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018419/class-with-same-name-in-two-assemblies-intentionally)

Suppose there are two different assemblies, both of which contain a class with the same name and the same namespace.

Is there a way to specify which version of the class I want to use?

Here's the actual scenario. I have an App that I created for wp7, that I want to upgrade to wp8. I used the LongListSelector from the WP7 Toolkit, which is now included in the WP8 standard SDK, but with some pretty major changes.
I would like to minimize code changes, so I would like to continue to use the one from the WP7 Toolkit, but the same class (LongListSelector) is included in the required assemblies for WP8 apps, so I had to remove the reference to the Toolkit. I'd like to keep both assemblies in the project, and use the LongListSelector class from the WP7 toolkit.

Is this possible?

Comment: Also, see Jon Skeet's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286632/what-use-is-the-aliases-property-of-assembly-references-in-visual-studio-8

Comment: Thanks, you're right, this is a duplicate. Sorry, should have done a better job searching.