# Resolve conflicts with imported types

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

I have a class MyClass under the namespace Phoenix in two different assemblies ClassLibrary1 and ClassLibrary2.
ClassLibrary2 is reference in ClassLibrary1.
Now in my ClassLibrary1 wherever I have made use of the MyClass type it gives me a warning of conflicts with imported types.
How can I resolve this without suppressing the warning using pragma directive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class with same name in two assemblies (intentionally)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018419/class-with-same-name-in-two-assemblies-intentionally)

Comment: what do you mean by "a reference in ClassLibrary1"? In general, if you have two classes in the same namespace you should not reference both assemblies. Why are you declaring the same class name in the same namespace in two different assemblies?

Comment: Well I think my question is a bit different. I am referencing ClassLibrary2 into ClassLibrary1. Now MyClass is present in both under the same namespace. I want to hide the warning that appears in ClassLibrary1 which wants to using the MyClass defined within itself, not from ClassLibrary2.

Comment: @Y.Ecarri its a code written earlier, and I don't have the liberty to change.

Answer (score 2):

Give an alias (other than the default 'global') to the `ClassLibrary2` reference in the `ClassLibrary1` project, by going into Properties on the reference itself.

This will get rid of the warning instantly in case you wanted to use the ClassLibrary1 version.

Now, whenever you want to access something from the ClassLibrary2 dll, you will need to place this on top of your class code:

```
extern alias <yourAliasName>;
using MyClassOther = yourAliasName::Phoenix.MyClass;
```

If you want to keep existing code that references other classes from `ClassLibrary1` working, you can keep the global alias and just add another alias to the reference. This way, you will just need the above code on classes that actually use `MyClass`. Then you will need to fully qualify the usage in (hopefully) a lot fewer cases.

Comment: Thanks @julealgon. Your answers seems appropriate though hundreds of errors have cropped up asking me to use this alias every where I have used ClassLibrary2 types. I think I will have to simply suppress the warning.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that happening. Though be aware of what version ends up being used (the warning states what has been chosen), as I've had problems with the algorithm before (VS2010 chose one while VS2012 chose another). Also, have you thought about just redesigning this? Why do you have two classes on the same namespace and with the same name to begin with? Are they actually the same class? You could just create a third assembly with this class if so, and reference it on both `ClassLibrary1` and `ClassLibrary2`.

Comment: I've edited the answer to show you a way to better handle the conflict in your situation, by using two aliases on the reference.