# System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1 exists in two assembly with same namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

> Error CS0433 The type 'HashAlgorithm' exists in both System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

I make a class library targets both `dnx46` and `dnxcore50`. When I reference HashAlgorithm class, visual studio 2015 give me above error. What is usual way to handle this situation? Use extern alias?

Comment: There is a change recently that one of the assemblies becomes obsolete. You should check .NET Core web site to see which should be removed.

Comment: @LexLi thanks to answer my question. I thought the same way. Both exists in the source code at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a fully qualified name, like

```
System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm
```

or you can have a look at [extern alias](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx), also check these questions:

[Class with same name in two assemblies (intentionally)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018419/class-with-same-name-in-two-assemblies-intentionally)

[Type exists in 2 assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194495/type-exists-in-2-assemblies)

Comment: The issue is both are same namespace just which is System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm

Comment: Thanks for that. Any idea how to add compile options in project.json file