# The imported type `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' is defined multiple times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This question is specific to Unity, this question has been asked before but not specifically for Unity.

I have 2 third party packages that have 2 dlls in their respective plugins directory:  fastjson.dll and newtonsoft.json.dll

I am getting the following errors:

The imported type `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' is defined multiple times
The imported type`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings' is defined multiple times

The reason is obvious, these 2 classes are defined in both dlls.  I have tried to delete one of the dlls to fix the problem but since there are other dlls in the package's plugin directories that depend on both of those dlls and so when I run a scene I get a file not found exception.

Short of getting the package creators to do something about it is there anything I can do to fix?

Comment: did you tried using extern alias and use fully qualified name for type ? you can refer how to do this [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ansonh/2006/09/27/extern-alias-walkthrough/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class with same name in two assemblies (intentionally)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018419/class-with-same-name-in-two-assemblies-intentionally)

Comment: The question you have marked as a possible duplicate is not specific to Unity. My question, and the correct answer supplied below, is for Unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bypass the conflict using an extern alias. Here is how to do so.

Create a file `mcs.rsp` in your `Assets` folder. Write something of this kind:

```
-reference:Newtonsoft=Assets/Plugins/newtonsoft.json.dll
```

Edit the path so it respects your project's architecture. (you can use fastjon.dll if you prefer to)

More about `mcs.rsp`: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html

Then, in the culprit .cs file, add the following:

```
extern alias Newtonsoft;

using UnityEngine;
using JObject = Newtonsoft::Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject;

// ...
```

Another solution would be to decompile (recent IDEs like Rider/MVS can do it for you) and rebuild yourself one of the managed DLL and rename the namespace. You may have to modify all scripts using the modified DLL.

Here are some guideline to create DLL for Unity (don't forget to compile with the -sdk:2.0 option, it is not specified in this document but it is required for your dll to work with Unity): https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html

By the way, send a request to the plugin maintainer to warn them about the namespace collision.

Comment: Awesome, I will try this out.  I was not aware of this solution.  Thank you!